# In ant given a true or false property how can I conditionally define a macrodef

Tags: ant, build, conditional-statements

I have a situation in a build file where I want two OS dependent versions of a macrodef and want to select which one gets "compiled" based on a flag that is true or false.

```
<condition property="use.windows.macros" value=true else=false
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

Pseudocode

```
if(use.windows.macrodef)
    <macrodef aMacro
       ... windows version
    </macrodef>
else
    <macrodef aMacro
       ... non windows version 
    </macrodef>
endif
```

how does one do this sort of thing with the basic out of the box ant xml nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - yes a synthesis of the prior partial answer and my work on it but this is what I ended up with as a structure.

I have to create two macros - the first creates the others based on the flags.

I'm not sure how this jibes with canonical ant but it does the job I need done and is easy for someone to see what is meant.

```
<condition property="os.windows">
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<condition property="os.linux">
    <os family="unix" name="linux" />
</condition>

<macrodef name="createOsMacros">
    <sequential if:set="os.windows">
        <macrodef name="doOsMacro">
            <attribute name="printstring" default="windows string"/>
            <sequential>
                <echo message="@{printstring}" />
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
    </sequential>
    <sequential if:set="os.linux">
        <macrodef name="doOsMacro">
            <attribute name="printstring" default="unix string"/>
            <sequential>
                <echo message="@{printstring}" />
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<createOsMacros />

<doOsMacro />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want two versions of macro? You can use only one (assuming you have ant version >= 1.9.3)

```
<project  xmlns:if="ant:if"  xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

    <condition property="os.windows">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="os.linux">
        <os family="unix" name="linux" />
    </condition>

    <macrodef name="sayHello">
        <sequential>
            <sequential if:set="os.windows">
                <echo message="hello from windows" />
            </sequential>
            <sequential if:set="os.linux">
                <echo message="hello from linux" />
            </sequential>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <sayHello />


</project>
```

Comment: 1.) you should emphasize that the new if/unless feature needs Ant 1.9.3 - it came with Ant 1.9.1 but had bugs that were fixed in 1.9.3    2.) the nested <sequentials> are obsolete, better : <sequential>
<echo message="hello from windows" if:set="os.windows"/>
<echo message="hello from linux" if:set="os.linux"/>
</sequential>

Comment: exactly I can only use one but for each OS i want what it contains to be different - this way the os specific item is factored out in one place and the version selected at runtime based on and adapted to the operating system running the script.

Comment: @peterk if:set / unless:set may be applied to all ant tasks, as shown in my comment <echo ... if:set=.../>

Comment: @Oleg I guess what I was thinking in the elegance sense is instead of having a constant (the os family derived value) apply to logic inside the macro - I was thinking more like the old C #if  #else #endif  where only the version for the current os is even parsed and only one valid version exists - in my case the default values for the arguments for windows have backslashes and they have forward slashes on unix etc. and they are in the declaration not the "code" also the shell is different on windows than unix so the way it handles "escapes" in the arguments is different, windows needs subshell

Comment: @Rebse yes, you can add if:set to echo, but I suppose that there are several statements inside the nested sequential, not just simple echo

Comment: @peterk the canonical way of programming in Ant is the one I've given in my answer. There are no C-like macros. I developed and maintained a big collection of ant build files running on windows, linux and aix. So I have some experience with Ant.